# How do I take the square root of a number in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How do I take the square root of a number in Elixir? There doesn't seem to be a `Math` module or anything, and there is no function like `sqrt()`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Elixir compiles to BEAM, which makes it compatible with Erlang modules. As you said, `:math.sqrt(x)` is essentially running Erlang code.

Answer (score 13):

Hah. Found it. You take the square root like this:

```
:math.sqrt(x)
```

Comment: You were right to ask - since it is never obvious when Erlang actually takes back responsibility in things Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

Also, since Elixir version 1.13, you can use [exponent syntax](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15.5/Kernel.html#**/2).

```
x ** 0.5
```

Comment: It appeared with Elixir 1.13 (or 1.14?), a recent version.

Comment: Yes, since version 1.13. Thanks, I corrected the answer :)